# Word count and it output

Tags: grep, tr, uniq

I have the following lines:

```
123;123;#rss
123;123;#site #design #rss
123;123;#rss
123;123;#rss
123;123;#site #design
```

and need to count how many times each tag appears, do the following:

`grep -Eo '#[a-z].*' ./1.txt | tr "\ " "\n" | uniq -c`

i.e. first select only the tags from the strings, and then break them down and count it.

output:

```
   1 #rss
   1 #site
   1 #design
   3 #rss
   1 #site
   1 #design
```

instead of the expected:

```
   2 #site
   4 #rss
   2 #design
```

It seems that the problem is in the non-printable characters, which makes counting incorrect. Or is it something else? Can anyone suggest a correct solution?

Comment: `uniq` requires the input to already by sorted; one quick fix would be `... | sort | uniq -c`; the `.*` says to match on zero or more of any character (including whitespace and non-printing characters) ... try `'#[a-z]+'` to limit to just lower case letters

Comment: Please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uniq -c` works only on sorted input.
Also, you can drop the `tr` by changing the regex to `#[a-z]*`.

```
grep -Eo '#[a-z]*' ./1.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

prints

```
  2 #design
  4 #rss
  2 #site
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a single `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS='#[a-zA-Z]+' 'RT {++freq[RT]} END {for (i in freq) print freq[i], i}' file

2 #site
2 #design
4 #rss
```

Or else a `grep + awk` solution:

```sh
grep -iEo '#[a-z]+' file |
awk '{++freq[$1]} END {for (i in freq) print freq[i], i}'

2 #site
2 #design
4 #rss
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk as an alternative:

```
awk -F [" "\;] '{ for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) {  map[$i]++ } } END { for (i in map) { print map[i]" "i} }' file
```

Set the field separator to a space or a ";" Then loop from the third field to the last field (NF), adding to an array map, with the field as the index and incrementing counter as the value. At the end of the file processing, loop through the map array and print the indexes/values.

Comment: `-F [" "\;]` should be `-F '[ ;]'`. Your array is keeping a count, not providing a mapping, so `cnt[]` or similar would be a more useful name for it than `map[]`. Also - `print map[i]" "i` = `print map[i], i` - let OFS have its reason to live :-).

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples only, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  while($0){
    match($0,/#[^ ]*/)
    count[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
END{
  for(key in count){
    print count[key],key
  }
}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2 #site
2 #design
4 #rss
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  while($0){                              ##Running while till line value.
    match($0,/#[^ ]*/)                    ##using match function to match regex #[^ ]* in current line.
    count[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++    ##Creating count array which has index as matched sub string and keep increasing its value with 1 here.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)          ##Putting rest of line after match into currnet line here.
  }
}
END{                                      ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(key in count){                      ##using for loop to go throgh count here.
    print count[key],key                  ##printing value of count which has index as key and key here.
  }
}
' Input_file                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cut -d';' -f3 file | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
      2 #design
      4 #rss
      2 #site
```